# Solving First Order Non Linear Differential Equation

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve the following question:

$\frac { dy }{ dx } ({ x }^{ 2 }{ y }^{ 3 }+xy)=1$

I took ***xy*** common and made the substitution

$x{ y }^{ 2 }=t$

On solving and simplifying after substitution I got

$\frac { dt }{ dx } -\frac { t }{ x } =\frac { 2 }{ t+1 } $.

Now I'm stuck up here.

I don't know what to do next.

Neither do I know what is first order non linear differential equation is nor do i know how to solve it.

(I typed the entire equation on **wolframalpha** and it showed it is a first order non linear differential equation).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you had to solve it and not, say, classify any equilibrium points? Because Wolframalpha shows a very complex set of solution steps.

Comment: I just got the answer and it was very complex. But it didn't show any steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following equation can be written as

${ x }^{ 2 }{ y }^{ 3 }+xy=\frac { dx }{ dy } $

Dividing LHS and RHS by ${ x }^{ 2 }$

We get

$\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \frac { dx }{ dy } -\frac { y }{ x } ={ y }^{ 3 }$

It's Bernouli Differential Equation.

Put  $\frac { 1 }{ x } =u$

Hence on differentiating with respect to **y** we get

$-\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } \frac { dx }{ dy } =\frac { du }{ dy } $

Putting the value in the original equation

$\frac { du }{ dy } +uy=-{ y }^{ 3 }$

Now this differential equation can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x^2y^3+xy)=1$$
$$(x^2y^3+xy)=\frac{dx}{dy}$$
$$x^2y^3+xy=x'$$
it's Bernoulli differential equation put $x=uv$ then $x'=u'v+uv'$
$$u'v+uv'-uvy=u^2v^2y^3$$
$$u'v+u(v'-vy)=u^2v^2y^3$$
$$v'-vy=0$$
$$v'=vy$$
$$\frac{dv}{v}=ydy$$
$$ln|v|=\frac{1}{2}y^2$$
$$v=e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}$$
$$u'\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}+u\cdot 0=u^2(e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2})^2y^3$$
$$u'=u^2\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}y^3$$
$$\frac{du}{u^2}= e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}y^3dy$$
$$-\frac{1}{u}=e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}(y-2)+c$$
$$u=-\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}(y-2)+c}$$
$$x=uv=-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}y^2}(y-2)+c}$$

Comment: How does $u'v+u(v'-vy)=u^2v^2y^3$ imply 
$v'-vy=0$?

Comment: I also didn't understand why is v'-vy=0.

Comment: this is Bernoulli method. we use two variables $u$ and $v$ instead $x$ and we cat put one condition for this variable, for example $v'-vy=0$

Comment: Ok thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Of cource the first integral is 
$$
{ x }^{ 2 }{ y }^{ 3 }+xy-x=C.
$$
It is a solution.

Comment: How is x^2*y^3+xy-x=C a solution?

Comment: it is an implicit form of a solution.. try some read about the first integral